# Horizontal acceleration on an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, free-body-diagram

Assume the inclined plane to be fixed. Taking components of gravitational acceleration along and perpendicular to the inclined plane and further taking a component of the component along the plane in the horizontal direction we can see that there is an acceleration in the horizontal direction due to gravity. But this shouldn't  be possible.

So what causes the horizontal acceleration. Also, why does taking component of the acceleration along the incline give the correct results anyway?

[image]

[Edit]
The horizontal acceleration is caused by the Normal reaction according to one of the answers. But even if that's the case, why is taking horizontal components of gsinA valid.

Comment: You seem to be missing the normal force on the block due to the inclined plane and its horizontal and vertical components.

Comment: @Farcher The Normal Force cancels out the component of gravity perpendicular to the plane right?

Comment: Also even if the normal causes horizontal acceleration taking components of the acceleration along the inclined plane still gives the correct results which further confuses me.

Comment: @Farcher Caution. Rabbit hole ahead !

Comment: @Bob D Gravity can not cause horizontal acceleration, so what does ? Is that insane to you.

Comment: @AdityaAhuja Resolving a vector into its  components is always valid. That includes resolving the component of a component of a vector into components

Comment: *why is taking horizontal components of gsinA valid.* Valid for what?

Comment: *Also, why does taking component of the acceleration along the incline give the correct results anyway?* Correct results for what? Also, note that the acceleration is entirely along the incline.

Comment: @AaronStevens I think we are talking about  components of the acceleration of the block with respect to the ground, no?

Comment: @BobD I am not sure. The OP keeps asking why things "correct" or "valid", but I am not sure what they are aiming to do in the first place. Certainly the acceleration has a component that is parallel to the ground, and it is moving relative to the ground, but it isn't "correct" or "incorrect" until the point of the analysis is established.

Comment: @AaronStevens I think the OP is struggling with the idea that you can further resolve the components of a vector into their components. But I'm also not sure.

Comment: @Bob D yes you are right taking components of a component confuses me.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens I now know that the normal is responsible for the horizontal acceleration and not Gravity. My professor,however,never mentioned the normal while calculating the horizontal acceleration (w.r.t ground) and just took components of gSinA (itself a component). In FissionChips answer he showed that using the normal reaction to calculate the horizontal acceleration gives the same result as taking the components of gSinA. The validity of this method is what confuses me.

Comment: @AdityaAhuja We are not taking the components of a component here at all. $g\sin A$ is the magnitude of the acceleration. The component of the acceleration in the parallel to the ground is then $g\sin A\cos A$. Just because you have 2 trig functions doesn't mean you are taking components of components of the acceleration.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens gSinA IS the component of gravitational acceleration in the the direction parallel to the incline.

Comment: $g\sin A$ is the acceleration due to the component of gravity along the incline, yes. But that then makes the acceleration's entire magnitude $g\sin A$. So while it comes from a component of gravity, it is not a component of the acceleration. The acceleration is a vector with magnitude $g\sin A$ and direction parallel to the incline. If you want to break this *single vector* into components parallel and perpendicular to the ground, then you can do that.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Do you mean that since the component of acceleration perpendicular to the plane cancels out with the normal,the only acceleration left  is the component of gravity along the incline which can be manipulated like any other vector ?

Comment: I prefer to think in terms of forces canceling out rather than accelerations canceling out. But yes, the net force is directed along the incline, so the acceleration is in that direction too. It has a magnitude of $g\sin A$. Then it just becomes a simple introductory vector problem. You have a vector with some magnitude and some direction, and you can choose to look at the component of the vector along some direction if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Edit] The horizontal acceleration is caused by the Normal reaction
>   according to one of the answers. But even if that's the case, why is
>   taking horizontal components of gsinA valid.

Resolving a vector into its components is always valid. That includes further resolving the component of a vector into its components.

So the acceleration down the plane is: $a$ = $g$ sin A.

The horizontal component with respect to the ground is: $a$ cos A = $g$ sin A cos A.

The vertical component with respect to the ground is: $a$ sin A =  $g$ sin A sin A = $g$ sin$^2$A

At A=45$^0$ the horizontal and vertical components of the acceleration with respect to the ground are the same.

Intuitively you can see that as A increases above 45$^0$ the horizontal component of the acceleration with respect to the ground down decreases and the vertical component increases, with the difference between the two widening the greater A becomes. When A reaches 90 degrees the horizontal component with respect to the ground is zero and the vertical component is g, i.e., the block is freely falling.

Going in the other direction with A less than 45$^0$ the acceleration down the plane is decreasing, and the opposite occurs. Both components of the acceleration with respect to the ground are decreasing, but now the horizontal component is greater than the vertical component, with the vertical component decreasing at a faster rate than the horizontal component. Eventually at A = 0$^0$ both components are zero.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The horizontal component of acceleration is not caused due to gravity. It is in fact caused due to the normal force applied by the inclined plane on the block.

The acceleration of the block is due to the resultant force on the block, and that will be due to the normal reaction as well as the gravitational force. But, we can say that the horizontal acceleration is caused by only the normal force, because we know that forces which act in a vertical direction cannot change the speed in the horizontal direction.

[image]

From 1, since acceleration perpendicular to incline is zero, we can see:
$$
                      N=mg cos⁡A           →eq1
$$
From 2 we can see that:
$$
a_{horizontal}=F_{horizontal}/m
$$
$$
F_{horizontal}=N sin⁡A
$$
Now, using eq.1:
$$
F_{horizontal}=(mg cos⁡A)sin⁡A 
$$
Finally:
$$
a_{horizontal}=(mg cos⁡A sin⁡A)/m
$$
$$
a_{horizontal}=g sin⁡A cos⁡A
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Avoid pen aper scree shot of the answers, try write it, and for more information use meta!

Comment: @YuvrajSingh... ok, I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: What @YuvrajSingh... Is trying to say is use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). And instead of keeping it in mind next time, you have a prefect opportunity to do it on this post using the edit feature :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a g.sin(A)cos(A) component in the + horizontal direction. But there is also a g.cos(A)sin(A) component in the - horizontal direction (from the component of weight normal to the inclined plane) that cancels it out.

Comment: so the horizontal motion is caused entirely by the normal reaction,right?

Comment: The component of weight parallel to the inclined plane causes acceleration along the surface. I'm not sure why you are concerned about the motion in the horizontal direction, but as the weight is directed downward, it cannot contribute to that and yes, the only force in the horizontal direction is the component of the normal force in that direction.

Comment: I am not specifically concerned about this problem . My original question is something different entirely which involves a trolly going down an inclined plane. In one of the steps we were required to calculate the horizontal acceleration which my professor calculated without considering the normal reaction and just took components of gsinA. Why does this give me the same result as the horizontal acceleration due to the normal reaction. Jujhaar Singh's answer used 2 different FBDs to explain this. Is this correct ?

Comment: I don't agree with the next to last step in Singh's post, where he is equating sin(A)/m to the horizontal component of the weight. The acceleration in the horizontal direction is just due to the component of the normal force in that direction. There is no net horizontal component of weight in the horizontal direction.

Comment: But he hasn't. He has made 2 different FBDs which consider different coordinate axes. He has then Substituted N for mgCosA. Also there is no horizontal component of weight. There is a component parallel to and a component perpendicular to the incline.

Comment: Okay. Got it. So he's expressing the horizontal component of the normal force in a way that is the same as your "acceleration in the horizontal direction due to gravity." So there are three acceleration components in the horizontal direction: the horizontal component of N, your "acceleration in the horizontal direction due to gravity" and as I pointed out an equal and opposite acceleration to this last one.

Comment: Also sayi that there is a component opposite to gSinACosA doesn't make sense since the body will show no horizontal motion in that case. There is,however, a component of gSinA perpendicular to the incline. Vector addition of these components gives us the resultant direction motion which is: down the incline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103696/discussion-between-aditya-ahuja-and-not-einstein).